# Dynamic switch statement for keypress (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hash, switch-statement, keydown

I've got a website that has full width and height `div`'s (each `div` is effectively a page) and you navigate through them using links and hashes; `<a href="#work"></a>` will scroll you to the page (full height `div`) with the `id` of `work`.

What I'm now trying to do is to use keypresses for navigation as well, so you can simply navigate through each page by pressing the up and down arrows.

I figured I could use a switch statement for this? what I'm having trouble with is making it dynamic. The way I thought of doing it was to use `window.location` and add the new hash onto the end every time a key was pressed, therefore going to the location with the corresponding `id`.

Using `if` statements I can do something like this..

```
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1), // get hash for current page
  url  = window.location.pathname; // get url

  if (hash == 'home' && e.keyCode == 40) { 
    window.location = url+'#about' // update location with new hash
  }
```

but I can't think how to do it using a switch statement. I need some way of checking the next hash to go to rather than setting it manually. I did some googling and found `nextAll` and thought I could use this to find the `attr` of the next `div` like so..

```
var hash = $('.what').nextAll('div:first').attr('id').substring(5);
hash = '#'+hash;
```

this works but obviously its only looking for the first `div` and won't update each time, how can I go about getting the next `div` so I can use a `switch` statement like so?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: window.location = url //url is equal to the next hash location
        break;
    case 38: window.location = url //url is equal to the previous hash location
        break;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="work_1" class="what scrollv">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>work 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="work_2" class="what scrollv">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>work 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="work_3" class="what scrollv">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>work 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas anyone? I really don't want to use a long if else statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)  instead.

```
var hash = $('.what').next().attr('id').substring(5)
```

`$('.what').next()` will give you `.what`'s next sibling.

**Edit:**

To keep track of which `div` is active, you could add an `.active` class like so:

```
var hash = $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').attr('id').substring(5);
```

`$('.active').next()` will then always give you the next div after `.active`.

Make sure to add the `.active` class to the `div` which is initially visible in your HTML.

**Edit 2:**

You can make it work when starting on any page by adding the `.active` class to the right `div`, based on the currrent `hash`, in the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1)
    $('#' + hash).addClass('active');
})
```

And changing the earlier line to:

```
var hash = $('.active').removeClass('active').next().attr('id').substring(5);
```

You won't have to set the `.active` class on an initial `div` in the HTML then.

Comment: that still returns just the next div after the first div with class what, i'll update to include some HTML

Comment: thanks, it works but only if I begin on the #home page, ideally I need it to work regardless or what page you begin on.. the if statements I have do work but they're really long so I was looking for a way to condense it and make it dynamic which yours is, just wondering if there's another way :/

Comment: I was sat here thinking about it and was implementing that myself just as your answer came through, thank you though!

Comment: It took me a while (lots of different scenarios I had to think about) but I've now got it all working as I want, thanks for your suggestions!